# node:internal/errors:464 ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err); Error Loop NODE

Tags: nodejs, api, axios, fetch, get

Buenas muchachos me encuentro consumiendo una Api con metodo GET, me pidieron extraer la información de algunos ID, por lo tanto cree una variable `const usersFounder = []` Donde guardare las ID encontradas para poder visualizarlas en el host, ademas agregue un for ya que me pidieron repetir el proceso con distintas ID, este es mi codigo.

```
const usersFounded = []
        var id = [
            '3123112313',
            '1231',
            '21',
            '923',
          ];
        for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
            fetch(`https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/vid/${id[i]}/profile?hapikey=${ hapikey }`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                usersFounded.push(data)
                console.log(usersFounded); 
                return res.status(200).send(usersFounded)
    
                            
                })
                .catch((error) =>{
                    console.log("Error al encontrar los contactos")
                    console.log(error);
                    return res.status(500).send(error)
                    
                })
                
                
          }
```

Al correr la api me encuentra tan solo el primer ID, pero los demás no logra encontrarlos, lanzándome el siguiente error

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
```

Cuando borro `.send(usersFounded)` me encuentra los ID pero no se me visualizan en el host.
A que se debera esto?

Answer (score 0):

intentaste utilizar las promesas para englobar ese bucle?

```
const bucleForWrapped = for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
  fetch(`https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/vid/${id[i]}/profile?hapikey=${ hapikey }`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      usersFounded.push(data)
      console.log(usersFounded); 
      return res.status(200).send(usersFounded)
  }).catch((error) =>{
    console.log("Error al encontrar los contactos")
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).send(error)
  })
}
Promise.all(bucleForWrapped)
```